# htaccess non-www to www rule doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

For a customer of mine I tried different versions of the `.htaccess` rule to forward/redirect all the "non-www" URL to the corresponding www one.

My current `.htaccess` is the following:

---

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# Redirection from non-www to www ---> latest rule used
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]


AddHandler application/x-httpd-php81 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

---

So...

I tried 3 different rules without any result (apart from having a 301 for the homepage ONLY).
My hosting is SG.
Any ideas/help?

I tried different rules, like the one published above and:

### #test 1 (same as above)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

### #test 2

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

### #test 3

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Nothing to do, none of these rules help me to redirect all the non-www URLs to the www ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the rule in the wrong place. This "redirect" rule needs to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block (rewrite to the WP front-controller), ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

Otherwise, any of your "tests" would work, although you are erroneously redirecting to `http` (not `https`) in "test2". You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive here (that already occurs *later* in the `.htaccess` file - in the WordPress code block).

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

By placing the rule at the end of the file (ie. *after* the WordPress front-controller pattern) then it's only going to be processed for the "homepage" and static assets - internal WordPress pages will not be redirected. (The "homepage", ie. the root directory, and static assets are not processed by the WordPress code block, so processing drops through to the rule at the end.)

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the clear answer, really appreciated. So... Like this?
# Redirection from non-www to www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=302]


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: So and if with 302 everything looks good, I could change it to 301, right? On the other hand, if something go wrong, with restoring a htaccess backup should I be ok, right? Thanks again!

Comment: @Bobby It's difficult to read unformatted code in comments, but yes, that looks about right. And yes, if the 302 works OK then change to a 301 (permanent) redirect. The "problem" with 301s is that they are persistently cached by the browser (and possibly other intermediate) cache(s). If there is an error with the redirect then the error also gets cached by the browser and you (and other users who have accessed the site in the meantime) see the "cached" error, even after changing the `.htaccess` file. In this case, "restoring a htaccess backup" will not help; the browser cache must be cleared.

Comment: You are a genius MrWhite!!! It works!!! Thank you for everything, great help, clear instructions, you solved my issue! Thank you for you help, really appreciated! :)